# html5 app not exiting correctly after updating to cordova 3.6

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I built my html5/js/css app using Cordova 3.5.0 couple of months back and few days back I received an email about vulnerabilities with that version so I need to update. I did update to Cordova 3.6.

My app is streaming music android app, which used to continue playing in the background once started and would be killed when we press the back button.

But, now on cordova 3.6, I find that the audio continues to play in the background even after back button exit and also, another issue is that, when one instance is running if I click on the app, it re-opens another instance.

This is really concerning as I am not really sure how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank!